# Use a clone of `thead` as `tfoot` so that they are equal

Tags: html, html-table

I'm currently developing an website that provides an overview of components and their version in different locations.

Therefore, the page contains a single `<select>` and a single `<table>`. Now I've come to wonder - is there anything that allows me to use my `<thead>` as the `<tfoot` as well?
I.e. something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <!-- content -->
  </thead>
  <tfoot equal-to-head="true"></tfoot>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
  <theadfoot>
    <!-- this would be equal to using thead and tfoot with the same content -->
  </theadfoot>
</table>
```

Now I'm developing my "website" with [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), so I could potentially write a component that does what I want. However, since I want to reduce code redundancy and not write even more code, that's not really the way to go.

Hence my question - does anybody know of an existing plugin (or even better, a built-in HTML functionality, although I doubt there is one) that one allows to combine `<thead>` and `<tfoot>`?